# Sharepoint Structural navigation- inserting query string in the url is not getting affected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, navigation, term

I have used structural navigation in my site.In site settings->Navigation,while specifying the url,I am not able to pass query string along with url. Example: http://sitecollection/page.aspx is accepted whereas http://sitecollection/page.aspx?k=hr is not working.While passing the query string along with url,query string is getting ignored.Can anyone suggest the root cause of this problem? Is this a sharepoint behaviour in terms of navigation?

Answer (score 3):

Write code as below:

```
string url = " http://sitecollection/page.aspx>k=hr";
string title = "HR";

SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode newnode = new SPNavigationNode(title, url, true);
web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast(newnode);
```

or another method is:

```
var newNode = new SPNavigationNode("HR", "http://sitecollection/page.aspx");
newNode = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsFirst(newNode);
newNode.Properties.Add("NodeType", "AuthoredLinkPlain");
newNode.Properties.Add("UrlQueryString", "k=hr");
newNode.Update();
```

You need to set the `IsExternal` property to true. After that it will start accepting query string or the second method which will add query string property to property bag.